# Django token : download server files with token authentification

Tags: python, django, jwt, token

I'm looking for set `token authentification` in order to download server files with secure way and add after an expiration time.

***Requirements :***

- Django 1.11
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Database PostgreSQL

***Process :***

User fills a form with some informations `CustomerForm(email, firstname, lastname and country)` and he has to choose one or several document(s) with checkboxes.

When form is submitted, I create an object with **user informations** + **document** choosen + **token** generated from `email + document_id + datetime` in `sha1` format.

User gets an email with download link according to previous document(s) (1 email per document).

***Expected :***

In this part I will explain what I would like to do, but I don't know how it's possible and this part is still fuzzy in my head. It's the first time I'm trying to do that.

User receives an email with url link based on token generated previously. When he clicks into the link, there is an authentification process which let to confirm user and open a window in order to download document file.

But, after few time (maybe 10 minutes) the token is expired and user have to submit the form a new time in order to get document file link.

As I said, it's a bit vague. I have to implement something like that, but I don't know how I could do that.

***My files :***

I have a class in my view which let to fill the form, generate token and send the email.

Then, I have this new class which let to compare `token` with database and compare `expiration_time` with `now()` too.

The issue is : if I open the link several time, `now()` is not actualized and my token is always valid and not expirate.

```
class TokenDownloadView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/token.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['token'] = self.kwargs['token']
        token = context['token']
        print(token)
        download = Download.objects.get(token__iexact=token)

        if download and download.expiration_date > now:
            print("token valide jusqu'à : " + str(download.expiration_date))
            print("il est actuellement : " + str(now))
            print(' ==> Token existe et valide <==')

        if download and download.expiration_date < now:
            print("token valide jusqu'à : " + str(download.expiration_date))
            print("il est actuellement : " + str(now))
            print('==> Token existe mais a expiré <==')

        return context
```

And this is what I obtain in my terminal in order to display what I said :

```
d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567
token valide jusqu'à : 2018-09-12 07:46:30.082915+00:00
il est actuellement : 2018-09-12 07:45:30.082915+00:00
 ==> Token existe et valide <==
[12/Sep/2018 09:45:42] "GET /crud/download/token/d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7447
[12/Sep/2018 09:45:42] "GET /static/css/common-8073709e.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567
token valide jusqu'à : 2018-09-12 07:46:30.082915+00:00
il est actuellement : 2018-09-12 07:45:30.082915+00:00
 ==> Token existe et valide <==
[12/Sep/2018 09:46:10] "GET /crud/download/token/d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7447
[12/Sep/2018 09:46:10] "GET /static/css/common-8073709e.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567
token valide jusqu'à : 2018-09-12 07:46:30.082915+00:00
il est actuellement : 2018-09-12 07:45:30.082915+00:00
 ==> Token existe et valide <==
[12/Sep/2018 09:46:30] "GET /crud/download/token/d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7447
[12/Sep/2018 09:46:30] "GET /static/css/common-8073709e.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567
token valide jusqu'à : 2018-09-12 07:46:30.082915+00:00
il est actuellement : 2018-09-12 07:45:30.082915+00:00
 ==> Token existe et valide <==
[12/Sep/2018 09:46:41] "GET /crud/download/token/d0ce9328a53032d4484cccff4c0bdd92ad701567/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7447
[12/Sep/2018 09:46:41] "GET /static/css/common-8073709e.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
```

Do you have any idea ?

I suspect cookies and it should be the case, but I don't know how I could remove cookie according to token ?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a url like the following, your logic in the `def get(...)` on `AppHomeView` could parse the token and check for timeout before allowing the download.  Also you'll probably want to use `LoginRequiredMixin` on `AppHomeView`.

Django 2.0

`path('download/<slug:token>/', views.AppHomeView.as_view(), name="download_document")`

Django 1.11

`url(r'^download/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.AppHomeView.as_view(), name='download_document')`

If you don't want to put the `def get(...)` on the `AppHomeView`, then you could just have two separate views and, following Django standard naming, call them `AppCreateView(CreateView)` and `AppDownloadView(View)` and implement the `def get(...)` that parses the token on the `AppDownloadView(View)`.  The corresponding url would be:

Django 2.0

`path('download/<slug:token>/', views.AppDownloadView.as_view(), name="download_document")`

Django 1.11

`url(r'^download/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.AppDownloadView.as_view(), name='download_document')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! What I've done but doesn't work up to now is on my last question edit. But I think it's lot of issues..

Comment: Not really unfortunately. And your url syntax `<int:token>` doesn't work I believe with Django 1.11, it was introduce with Django 2.0

Comment: I added the Django 1.11 syntax for the urls.  Are you able to resolve the url and get your view logic to execute (whether or not it's executing correctly)?